# VBA Function not returning HTMLElementCollection object

Tags: html, vba, excel, function, return-value

I'm attempting to return a HTMLElementCollection from a function. However, function-wise everything works as it should, but when the code returns to the calling sub, the variable assigned to the Functions output, "myTable", shows "< No Variables >". I've tried passing the collection back as part of a scripting.dictionary but with the same result.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks all.

```
Sub updateReports()
'//Function gathers latest report information and adds to sheets("Reports")
'//URL
Dim strURL As String
    strURL = "http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=62103"

        Dim myTable As HTMLElementCollection
        Set myTable = getTable(strURL)
        '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
        'From here on, "myTable" listed as '<No Variables>'.
        'HTMLElementCollection not sucessfully returned.
        '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
End Sub

Public Function getTable(strURL As String) As Variant
'//Downloads HTML Table from strURL
'//Create HTTP Object
Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
        oXMLHTTP.send

Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oXMLHTTP.responsetext
        Set getTable = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")()
        '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
        'Under "getTable" call stack, getTable shows correct object (HTMLElementCollection)
        '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I think I figured it out what's going on... Try creating the HTMLDocument in the main sub (updateReports) and pass it to the getTable function through an byRef Argument. Also change the returning type of the function to HTMLElementCollection. Something like that:

```
Sub updateReports()
'//Function gathers latest report information and adds to sheets("Reports")
'//URL
Dim strURL As String
    strURL = "http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=62103"

        Dim myTable As HTMLElementCollection
        Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument

        Set myTable = getTable(strURL, HTMLDoc)
        '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
        'From here on, "myTable" listed as '<No Variables>'.
        'HTMLElementCollection not sucessfully returned.
        '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
End Sub

Public Function getTable(strURL As String, ByRef HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument) As HTMLElementCollection
'//Downloads HTML Table from strURL
'//Create HTTP Object
Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
        oXMLHTTP.send

    If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oXMLHTTP.responsetext
        Set getTable = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")()
        '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
        'Under "getTable" call stack, getTable shows correct object (HTMLElementCollection)
        '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    End If
End Function
```

Let me know if this works out for you!

Comment: Hi Adriano. Thanks for the response.
I tried what you said and it worked. I then made one modification at a time to pin-point the issue exactly. 
Turns out it was the initialisation of the HTMLDocument in the main sub, and passing this into the function as a parameter. I guess the HTML object body first needs to be initialised in the sub if i want to use it's library?!
Anyway, Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It is just a guess, but I think that when you initialize the HTMLDoc in the function, this object gets destroyed when you leave the function. So myTable tries to call the getElementsByTagName on Null, because HTMLDoc object was destroyed. You correct that by initializing the object in main, and it will stay alive until the end of execution.